Does keycloak exposes any REST API for passwordless web authentication during user register
Does Keycloak exposes any REST API for password-less web authentication during user register, i want an spring-boot API which internally calls the password-less authentication during user register , i don't want to expose the UI of keycloak
i want an API of spring-boot which calls the keycloak password-less authentication during user signup
